# When a troop upgrade finishes do existing troops get upgraded?

Tags: boom-beach

When you do a troop upgrade, for example to upgrade Riflemen from lvl 10 to lvl 11, will any existing Riflemen (which were recruited at lvl 10 and therefore the lvl 10 price) then be lvl 11 Riflemen once the upgrade completes?

Comment: Yes. If troops in your boats will also be upgraded. There is also one exploit here, lets say you are upgrading heavies, then you can load all your boats with them and unload later once upgrade is done. You can get few extra coins by doing so.

Comment: Good observation, I'll keep it in mind next time I do a troop upgrade and test it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any existing troops will be upgraded to their new level after the upgrade finishes. While the upgrade is not finished yet, they will still be their previous level.